# Can I create an "image" of a virtual network?

Tags: networking, virtualization

I've built a network consisting of a firewall, VPN and several virtual machines. I built this on my university's virtual network. The university uses VMWare.

Is it possible to create a sort of "image" of the entire network so I could deploy it on something like azure or my own hardware.

NOTE: this is not a school project. I'm just trying to learn about this topic in my free time.

Comment: Do you have access to ESXi or VSphere?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes. Potentially, I could ask the administrators for something if I know exactly what it is they need to give me.

Comment: In that case, have a look at this https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2042141 and https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcli.examples.doc%2Fcli_manage_hosts.4.4.html

Comment: Ever heard of GNS3? You can create very large (depending on HW) virtual networks. It also runs actual router and switch firmware, and I believe can be saved with the configurations you apply to it.